Show $G$ is 2- connected
Let $G$ be a graph on at least 3 vertices. Suppose that $\chi(G) = k$ but $\chi(G−v) < k$ for every $v \in V(G)$.
Show that G is 2-connected.
My proof: Suppose we have $v$, such that $G-v$ is has at least two connected components, say $G_i s$, we know $\chi(G_i)<k$, then how can we show adding back $v$, we do not need one more color, so that contradict the assumptions that $\chi(G) = k$
Observe : $\chi(G_i\cup v) <k$. Indeed there is a stronger statement. Suppose $H$ is a proper subgraph of $G$ with strictly less vertices (for example, say without $v$), then $\chi(H) \leq \chi(G-v) < k$.
SO we can color all of the $G_i \cup v$ using $k-1$ colors, I can permute so that $v$ gets the same color in all of the $G_i \cup v$. (That is because each color class is an independent set)

It’s not clear what you mean. You suggest that you have a proof, but one sentence of it is a question.

Your "proof" is not proof. Imagine two triangles with a single common vertex $v$, let's call this graph $G$. Removing $v$ yields two components, each requiring two colours. However, $\chi(G)=3$. You must use the fact that $\chi(G-v)<k$ for EVERY $v\in V(G)$

Yes, that is not a full proof because I did not figure it out thoroughly, but now I add more details for a proof. Help me check whether I am wrong. Thank you.

Yes, this addition makes your proof complete.
